# Proper way to monitor PostgreSQL running inside a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos7

I'm running a docker container with **CentOS 7 + PostgreSQL 9.4**. Using [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/postgresql-94-centos7/).

So, after pulling the image, I've created the container, following the instructions, and exposing the PostgreSQL port 5432.

Of course, I can execute a shell in my container, by doing this

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

After that, I'm logged as **postgres user**. But I need to **install more software** (basically, postgres related stuff, or some command line tools).

**EDIT: What I'd need, for example, is to install the lsof tool (not available by default in CentOS 7, can be installed with yum install lsof).**

So, **I'd need a different user, able to install software**. Unless...

I'm not doing things the right way, and what I really need is **another container to monitorize PostgreSQL**. Or even use **my host machine** (Mac OS X) for that. But then... **How could I use commands like lsof, or htop**? I need to be in the same container that runs PostgreSQL for that.

Am I right?

Comment: Upvote for the word "monitorize".  Not sure what it means in this context or any other but I like it

Comment: Wow, sorry for that. Weird English (not my mother tongue). Fixed :-D :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was easy

```
docker exec -it -u root CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash -c "yum install lsof"
```

Comment: yes, but in order to keep lsof inside, you will have to `docker commit`see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ and use then the commited image. Maybe you should create another image with a Dockerfile beginning with `FROM mkurnikov/postgresql-9.4` and having also yout lsof installation

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip. I see keeping my changes in a Dockerfile is a better idea. But the file you point at (https://github.com/mkurnikov/docker-postgresql/blob/master/Dockerfile) is based on Debian. I want to base my installation in CentOS 7. Anyway, many thanks again!